# Append Select Option to Text Field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Select Box and a Text Field input box.  Currently when the User selects a value from the Select Box, then the selected value is inputted into the Text Field input box.

```
<select name="nSupervisor" id="iSupervisor" onchange="PopulateUserName()">
        <option value="fff">fff</option>
        <option value="test1">test1</option>
        <option value="dd">dd</option>    
    </select>  
<input id="iSupervisorUserName" name="OBKey_WF_Manger_Supervisor_1" type="text" />

function PopulateUserName() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("iSupervisor");
    var field = document.getElementById("iSupervisorUserName");
    field.value = dropdown.value;
}
```

Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Hx6J5/1/

Currently it only takes one input.

I would like it to append inputs so the field will accept more than one select value, so if the User selects "fff", "fff" will get inputted into the field.
If the User then selects "dd", the field.value should become "fff/dd" with the "/" being the separator.

```
function PopulateUserName() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("iSupervisor");
    var field = document.getElementById("iSupervisorUserName");
$('field').val($('field').val() + dropdown.value);

}
```

I have tried this but it doesn't append.

Comment: don't use quote on field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give field without quotes. If field is given in quotes jQuery will try to find elements with tag name field.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx6J5/6/)**

```
$(field).val($(field).val() + dropdown.value);
```

Comment: This works too, $(field).val($(field).val() + dropdown.value); check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/Hx6J5/6/

Answer (score 0):

Using pure JS:

```
function PopulateUserName() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("iSupervisor");
    var field = document.getElementById("iSupervisorUserName");
    if ( field.value == "" ){
        field.value = dropdown.value;   
    }else{
        field.value += "/" + dropdown.value;
    }
}
```

See the working code at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sx338/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use multi select jquery plugin:
http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/